# Selenium ChromeDriver returns 403 errors on build server

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver

We've created a Selenium test project that starts the (ASP.NET) web application and runs a couple of tests using the ChromeDriver. Locally this all runs fine (in headless and non-headless mode).

But on the build server (using an Azure DevOps agent) this fails without ever starting the tests. It looks like it fails when starting the ChromeDriver: the driver starts, but then it's immediately followed by 403 errors. It never gets to the part where it actually loads a webpage.

Any ideas where to look?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question to document possible solutions.

After some rigorous investigation (which included using [the source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/trunk/dotnet/src/webdriver) to get to the bottom of things) we found out that the proxy server somehow got in the way. It turned out that the ChromeDriver tries to communicate over a local port (e.g. http://localhost:12345), which was redirected through the proxy server. This failed with a 403 error.

This gave us a lead on possible solutions. First we tried to use [the .proxybypass file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) to exclude localhost addresses. This didn't work -- it turns out that this proxy bypass only works for https requests. And the ChromeDriver control commands are sent over http :-(

We then made sure that no proxy was used in our test code. We did this with the following lines:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
options.AddArgument("headless");
options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
options.Proxy = new Proxy()
    {
        Kind = ProxyKind.Direct
    };

var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

In addition to these settings (note that some arguments were added to solve other issues and might not apply to your own situation), we also disabled the proxy for other requests:

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null; 
HttpClient.DefaultProxy = new WebProxy()
{
    BypassProxyOnLocal = true,
};
```

This allowed our tests to finally run on the build server without the 403 errors.
One last remark (which might be obvious) is to always run your tests in non-headless mode if you encounter any issues. This allowed us to see the "invalid certificate error" which would otherwise be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced the same problem, and the following solution was what fixed it. Maybe it will work better in some cases.

First, add this dependency to your POM:

```
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <version>4.8.1</version>
  <artifactId>selenium-http-jdk-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Second, add this line of code somewhere either in early in your main method or better yet in a Junit @BeforeClass:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");
```